# Modular S-matrix of (p,q) minimal model

Tags: reference-request, conformal-field-theory

What is the expression for the modular S-matrix of (p,q) minimal model? The Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_(physics) does not provide S-matrix

Comment: Could be wrong but it seems that it's given as formula 23b of the original article by Capelli, Itzykson and Zuber in Communications in Mathematical Physics https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-113/issue-1/The-rm-A-rm-D-rm-E-classification-of-minimal/cmp/1104160138.full I think $N=2pq$ and characters are encoded by integers $\lambda$ mod $N$.

Comment: Sorry Cappelli with two p's.

Comment: According formula 23b, the matrix elements of S-matrix is just a phase factor/sqrt(N), which seems not right for minimal models.

Comment: Sound like you are confusing the notion of S-matrix with that of S-matrix. Some S-matrices in the scattering sense  are "kinda trivial" when they are diagonal with diagonal elements made of of phase factors. The matrix from 23b is not diagonal.

Comment: Of course in the first sentence of the last comment I am only kidding.

Comment: According formula 23b, all the matrix elements of modular S-matrix has a form S_ij = exp(i phi) / sqrt(N), which seems not right for minimal models.

Comment: Yes, it is close to the correct formula but not quite there because of some extra steps missing. See my 2nd comment to Sylvain's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modular S-matrix appears in Section 10.6 of the Big Yellow Book by di Francesco, Mathieu and Sénéchal. For a freely available reference, there are my lecture notes https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09523 , eq. (A.28).

The Wikipedia article on minimal models was mostly written by someone who does not like the modular bootstrap. But you are free to complete it.

Comment: Apart from different notations, your formula A28 seems to the be same as the formula 23b from the CIZ paper I mentioned.

Comment: Oh I see, there is indeed a difference due to reduction to a discrete fundamental  domain. In the 1997 edition of the yellow book, the formula 23b I mentioned is 10.128 and is a preparatory step for the S-matrix a few lines below, formula 10.132 (recapped and boxed in 10.134) which is your formula A28.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly want I was looking for.